# How to make shortcuts for these Steam games/"subgames"?

Tags: steam, shadow-warrior

The Steam right-click menu for *Shadow Warrior Classic Redux* allows me to play the game expansions *Wanton Destruction* and *Twin Dragon*.

If I utilize the option in the same right-click menu to **Create Desktop Shortcut**, the resulting shortcut takes me right to the original game.

How can I create a desktop shortcut for each of the expansions?

(I am running Steam on a Linux system, if it matters)

[image]

Comment: I wonder two things: if there are launch options for this particular game that allow you to start it up straight to that "subgame" and if you can then just create a desktop shortcut that runs the game using said launch option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a shortcut to the main game Shadow Warrior, and add `-addon1` for Wanton Destruction, `-addon2` for Twin Dragon.

Or just copy the following lines:

- Shadow Warrior: Wanton Destruction: `steam://rungameid/225160//-addon1`
- Shadow Warrior: Twin Dragon: `steam://rungameid/225160//-addon2`

Comment: Thanks. Away from home for a few days, will test when I get back.

Comment: Is the addon order relative to purchase date? Am wondering if it'll always be addon1 = Wanton Destruction, or if it's going to be relative to the order displayed in the context menu.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I believe it has to do with release date.

Comment: This worked! I get an additional "verify game launch options" box I have to click OK on, but that's acceptable.

Comment: @Joachim apologies, I thought I had. done.

Comment: @OrganicMarble No problem at all!